# why do i get a bad file descriptor error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, server

i got an error for bad file descriptor for this code for the udp server program i made

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 890))

while True:
   (c,a) = s.recvfrom(1024)
   msg = 'thanks for requesting'
   s.sendto(msg,a)
   s.close()
```

the error message i got was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "udpserv.py", line 7, in <module>
(c,a) = s.recvfrom(1024)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

can anyone please tell me how i got this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 9):

You get this error because you `close` the socket and then call `recvfrom` again.

If you add a `print` after the line with `recvfrom`, you'll notice that the first call to `recvfrom` works as expected. The second call (after looping once) throws the error you see.

Fix your code by simply removing `s.close()`. (You don't need to close the connection to the client as UDP doesn't have that concept, in contrast to TCP if you had that in mind.)

Answer (score 1):

You can get that same error if you have an infinite while loop. In my case I replaced the

```
while True:
```

with

```
count = 0
while (count < 10):
    count += 1
    #rest of the code
```

Comment: But what if you want an infinite while loop?

Comment: How would this cause an error? I've written loads of programs that rely on an infinite loop to run until something happens, and I've never encountered such a problem.