# "Exception in thread Thread-3" Python exception killing ROS node

Tags: python, multithreading, ros

I am trying to build a slam algorithm using python scripts and ROS. I have a top-level workspace which has two packages, one is the (rplidar_ros) package from GitHub and the other is the (slam) package I built using catkin_create_pkg which has an src directory that has two python files icp.py and mapping.py, a msg directory with a custom topic defined in Custom.msg and a launch directory with icp.launch.My problem is that when I use `roslaunch` to launch all three nodes, the `rplidar_ros` and `icp_node` launch fine and keep alive. map_node though dies immediately as soon as its started and then respawns and then dies again and continues this cycle.

When each node is run independently not using `roslaunch`, if the icp_node is run before map_node, map_node produces the same cycle of shutting and starting. But if map_node is started before icp_node it gives this error -

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 154, in run
    (client_sock, client_addr) = self.server_sock.accept()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 206, in accept
sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: Please put on your code snippet. Apparently, you need a `try, except` on `Thread-3`

Comment: Check your code if you are trying to use a closed socket. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966374/why-do-i-get-a-bad-file-descriptor-error/45239295